# When I used gradle5.0 to build my project.It caused java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.How to solve it?

Tags: java, gradle

I used to use gradle3.5 and gradle4.0 to build my project, which works.
But when I download gradle5.0 and set my gradle path to gradle5.0. Then I build the same project with the same build command, it causes an oom error.

```
gradle build -x test -x checkstyleMain -x checkstyleTest
```

> Task :cok-common:compileJava FAILED

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position$LineMapImpl.build(Position.java:153)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position.makeLineMap(Position.java:77)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.getLineMap(JavaTokenizer.java:763)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.getLineMap(Scanner.java:127)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseCompilationUnit(JavacParser.java:3173)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:628)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:665)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
```

Comment: Build on linux.

Comment: Now this I have yet to see happen. I would assume that your computer didn't have much RAM available when you ran this (a lot of other programs running?). Look into that first.

Comment: But when I use gradle3.5 to build the same project with the same command.It will not caused oom error.  @tomtzook

Comment: There were a lot of changes between gradle 3.5 and 5. Did you define gradle to run as daemon (org.gradle.daemon=true)? This was also a change in 5. What are your properties in general? If your computer has memory, try to increase the JVM heap size https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:configuring_jvm_memory.

Comment: I add org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m in my project's gradle.properties. But it still caused oom error.It seems that the properties don't work.@tomtzook

Answer (score 0):

1. Setting Java Environment (in build setting and gradle setup)

+java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:  Java heap Space

+java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen Space

So at first, you say it is ok in old version of gradle ~> Heap Space seem okay.

If not you can try: -Xmx512M (2048M if you think so) Be careful with 3 option of HeapSize (Init size, Max Heap Size, Minimum Size)

For PermGen, it is default 64M and use to save metadata and  String pool.

Maybe Gradle 5 use more meta data, so this can be a problem (which hard to detect)

```
export JVM_ARGS = “- XX: PermSize = 64M -XX: MaxPermSize = 256m”
```

You can check to change the size of Perm

Comment: I add org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m in my project's gradle.properties. But it still caused oom error.It seems that the properties don't work.

Comment: Maybe try to profile the gradle heap usage with: https://github.com/gradle/gradle-profiler. Because it sounds insane.